# Auto-reloading of code changes with Django development in Docker with Gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn, docker-compose

I'm using a Docker container for Django development, and the container runs Gunicorn with Nginx. I'd like code changes to auto-load, but the only way I can get them to load is by rebuilding with docker-compose (`docker-compose build`). The problem with "build" is that it re-runs all my pip installs.

I'm using the Gunicorn `--reload` flag, which is apparently supposed to do what I want. Here are my Docker config files:

```
## Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.4.3
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements/docker.txt

## docker-compose.yml:
web:
  restart: always
  build: .
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000 --reload

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./config/nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

I've tried some of the other Docker commands (`docker-compose restart`, `docker-compose up`), but the code won't refresh.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have shared volume with your code? Can you post part of your docker-compose.yml to view the scenario?

Comment: I d not understand your "The problem with "build" is that it re-runs all my pip installs. " Maybe you can do first all the pip installs, so that `docker build` only loads code changes. Can you show your Dockerfile? You can also have a Dockerfile starting with `FROM mypipinstalls`

Comment: kikicarbonell, your question helped me realized I needed a volume for my code, and that appears to have fixed my issue, so thanks for leading me to the solution!

Comment: @user2915097, while I think I resolved my issue by adding the code volume, I am curious on what your suggesting. How would `FROM mypipinstalls` work (i.e., compared to what I'm doing now -- see above, I added my config files)?

Comment: to any subsequent reader, @user2915097 is surely making reference to multistage builds. You could use that to create layers that would not change if you were to rebuild your docker-compose app. But going that way just to reload code is kindda overkill, I suggest sticking to shared volumes.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Thanks to kikicarbonell, I looked into having a volume for my code, and after looking at the [Docker Compose recommended Django setup](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/), I added `volumes: - .:/code` to my web container in docker-compose.yml, and now any code changes I make automatically apply.

```
## docker-compose.yml:
web:
  restart: always
  build: .
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app/static
    - .:/code
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000 --reload
```

*Update:* for a thorough example of using Gunicorn and Django with Docker, checkout this [example project from Rackspace](https://github.com/rackerlabs/guestbook), which also shows how to use docker-machine to launch the setup on remote servers like Rackspace Cloud.

**Caveat:** currently, this method does not work when your code is stored locally and the docker host is remote (e.g., on a cloud provider like Digital Ocean or Rackspace). This also applies to virtual machines if your local file system is not mounted on the VM. Note that there are separate volume drivers (e.g., flocker), and there *might* be something out there to address this need. <strike>For now, the "fix" is to rsync/scp your files up to a directory on the remote docker host. Then, the `--reload` flag will auto-reload gunicorn after any scp/rsync.</strike>  **Update:** If pushing code to remote docker host, I find it far easier to just rebuild the docker container (e.g., `docker-compose build web && docker-compose up -d`). This can be slower though than the rsync approach if your src folder is large.

Comment: I thought inotify didn't work with Docker volumes. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18246

Any idea why this works?

Comment: @EricIhli -- This method does not work when the docker host is remote (because the volume declarations in the Compose file are with respect to the docker host). I've updated my answer with a disclaimer clarifying this.

Comment: Ah. Thanks.
I did solve my problem of needing to watch file changes and do some action inside a container by using 'fswatch' on Mac, piping through to 'xargs', and running 'docker exec <container> <command>', in case anyone else is looking for that.

Comment: I am seeing an intermittent behaviour on my Mac (both Docker and Django are local). Sometimes it auto-reloads, sometimes it doesn't, which makes development really difficult. Anyone seen this behaviour before? @EricIhli

Comment: Thanks for this "--reload" for gunicorn, which saved my day

Comment: It seems like you need to match your WORKDIR/COPY commands in your Dockerfile in your docker-compose.yml. Here is an example:

Dockerfile
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

docker-compose.yml
app:
    / other commands / 
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app

Comment: Have to add the command --reload plus the .:/app/
command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000 --reload

Comment: is docker compose necessary?

Answer (score 34):

You have another problem- Docker caches each layer that it builds.  You shouldn't have to re-run pip install every time!

```
ADD . /code/
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements/docker.txt
```

This is your problem- Docker checks every ADD statement to see if any files have changed and invalidates the cache for it and every later step if it has.  The correct way to do this is...

```
ADD ./requirements/docker.txt /code/requirements/
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements/docker.txt
ADD ./code/
```

Which will only invalidate your pip install line if your requirements file changes!

Comment: I was wondering why the ADD was redundant. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you need to match your WORKDIR/COPY commands in your Dockerfile in your docker-compose.yml when creating the volume. Here is an example:

Dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
app:
    / other commands / 
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced very similar problem trying to configure auto-reload of the project with a little bit different setup. I set up volumes but it did not work anyway. After an hour of googling and thorough examination of my code I figured out that volume **paths in Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml simply do not match**. Make sure that they are the same.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.9-alpine3.10

COPY ./requirements/local.txt /app/requirements/local.txt

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps postgresql-dev git gcc libgcc musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev build-base \
    && python -m venv /env \
    && /env/bin/pip install --upgrade pip \
    && /env/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements/local.txt \
    && runDeps="$(scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /env \
        | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -r apk info --installed \
        | sort -u)" \
    && apk add --virtual rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps

### Here is the path to the project
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/project

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

EXPOSE 8088
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'


services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: compose/local/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8088 --settings=project.settings.local
    volumes:
      # - .:/var/www/app  # messed up path
      - .:/app  # correct path
    env_file:
      - ../../.env.local
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I never found a desirable solution consider this interesting hack. Posting here I wanted to see if anyone has similar/good/bad experiences with this "work around".

To make code reload locally for development I simply created a View that immediately calls `exit()`.  The exit will crash Django and a reload will occur where code changes are available.  The reboot takes a fraction of a second and can be done via a tab in the browser, a `requests.get` call, or any other similar call. The reload is not automatic but it does skip any Docker lag such as a restart.

When the exit is called you will see the PID increment (if tailing logs):

```
web    | [2019-07-15 18:29:52 +0000] [22] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22)
web    | [2019-07-15 18:29:52 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
```

I hope this helps others and/or gets feed back on this approach.

Comment: If you're using gunicorn for your local development, the `--reload` flag will use your latest code automatically, assuming your local code is being read from a shared volume between docker and your local box.  If you're having issues with this setup and want to pursue it further, I'm happy to help you debug the issue, but you should start a new question and link back in these comments.

Comment: @DolanAntenucci Thanks for the response. Every project is set up different, so ``--reload`` is not always an option.  This "work around" may help others patch a bad situation.

Comment: @DolanAntenucci, follow up - I did some testing on the flag and it is generally reliable, but not 100%. I feel like ~1 in 10 times the code did not update and I needed to use an alternative.  The Docker set up (inherited) may be causing interference, not sure but again thanks b/c in this project `--reload` generally works.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I do recall having `--reload` not 100%, but I forget if there was a particular situation where it didn't work. Actually, in Celery workers would be one example; that requires a restart

Comment: Docker is not a standard, so I am glad to have an alternative.  Celery does require "code reload" as it is a background application interfacing w/the Python code, I remember in VENV and PIPENV needing to restart that service for code edits, love to get that improved, but the inconvenience is low.

Answer (score 1):

I you use docker-compose:

1. **DockerFile**: When you build image from Dockerfile you need to add some directory to save your code (in my case /api/):

   `WORKDIR /api/` -> important

   `COPY . .` -> important

[image]

2. **Docker-compose**: Your docker-compose file haves you app service with the image in django just builded from Dockerfile, now you need to add the volume with the same WORKDIR that you use in Dockerfile:

`volumes:`
`- .:/app` -> important

[image]

And is all.