# Set up development environment for multiple Django apps in vagrant that allows instant update

Tags: python, django, vagrant

I have set up a virtual environment using vagrant, and virtualbox.

The virtual environment uses ubuntu 14.04 the production OS.

I want to have multiple django apps using this same virtual machine setup.

**What I expect**

Whenever I edit any python file or html on my macbook using my favorite editor (such as Vim or Sublime), the change is immediate whenever I press refresh on my browser (also in my macbook OS)

The django app is reached via a url such as http://djangoapp1. Other apps could be http://djangoapp2, etc

All these urls are actually pointing to the same vagrant machine.

When I want to edit the database (postgres), I only need to run valentina studios in my macbook and it will connect to the postgres database running inside the virtual machine.

**What actually happened**

I spent a lot of time getting multiple django apps to work in the same machine using nginx and uwsgi.

Then I realise whenever i make changes, the change is not reflected instantaneously. I needed to add a --touch-reload to the uwsgi process which is now started using upstart.

Even when I did add --touch-reload, I still had to deliberately go and "touch" a file whenever I want to reflect my code changes.

Even when it is done, the change doesn't always show up for some reason. It only shows up when I did a proper `vagrant halt` and then `vagrant up`. `Vagrant reload` causes the entire app to crash.

The only way I can have the code change > refresh web page > see change cycle is when I use the native `manage.py runserver`

But that means I cannot easily switch between apps during development. I have to shut one down and then start another one.

If I did the same using CakePHP or any kind of PHP frameworks to build multiple apps in the same virtual machine, I can have the make code change > refresh page > see changes development cycle.

**How do I achieve the same ease for multiple Django apps in the same virtual machine while using my home OS to write code?**

Comment: did you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/32029035/4296747 setup is for docker but logic could be applied for vagrant

Comment: I am neither fluent with vagrant nor docker. That answer did not help

Comment: When you say "multiple django apps" you mean they are all in different django projects or all of them are in the same django project?

Comment: Different django project

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet will use Django's autoreloader to detect code changes, and hook into uWSGI to reload the code whenever necessary:

```
import uwsgi
from uwsgidecorators import timer
from django.utils import autoreload

@timer(3)
def change_code_gracefull_reload(sig):
    if autoreload.code_changed():
        uwsgi.reload()
```

You can put this code in your `wsgi.py` file before `get_wsgi_application()`. The decorator will register the function to be run every 3 seconds by uWSGI.

([Original source](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/TipsAndTricks#uWSGIdjangoautoreloadmode))

Comment: Is this also how u do it for your own local development?

Comment: Yes, this is what I use in my own vagrant box.

Answer (score 0):

> --touch-reload

As I known this arg is used for a specific configuration `.ini` file.
Please try with option `--py-autoreload 1`.

At development phase, I think you can use Nginx proxy directly to default `runserver` or `runserver_plus` (please check `django-extensions`)

Comment: My question mentioned that i have tried touch-reload and didn't work.

Comment: No, I mean that --touch-reload is not the right way to fit your requirements.
I've mentioned `--py-autoreload 1`. Have you tried it?